# Custom range chart ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, charts, mpandroidchart

[image: line chart]

I have a requirement to display data in a chart and tried https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts library to customize bar chart or candle stick chart. But I am not able to achieve this type of UI. Is there any other library or suggestion to achieve this?

Comment: Core Plot may be able to do that. https://github.com/core-plot

Comment: Apple just announced the Charts framework which can create a range chart. It's still in beta at this time though. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Charts